# How to implement placefilter by gym, hospital in PlaceDetectionClient

Tags: java

How to implement placefilter by gym, hospital  in PlaceDetectionClient

```
Task<PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse> placeResult =  mPlaceDetectionClient.getCurrentPlace(null);

placeResult.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse> task) {
        Log.d(TAG, "current location places info");
        List<Place> placesList = new ArrayList();
        PlaceLikelihoodBufferResponse likelyPlaces = task.getResult();
        for (PlaceLikelihood placeLikelihood : likelyPlaces) {
             placesList.add(placeLikelihood.getPlace().freeze());
        }
        likelyPlaces.release();  }}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the "Nearby Search" functionality you want is not in the Android SDK.

The [Google Maps Place Search API](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search) has what you want:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json
  ?key=api-key
  &location=latitude,longitude
  &radius=meters
  &rankby=prominence|distance
```

Heed this warning:

> By default, when a user selects a place, Nearby Search returns all of the available data fields for the selected place, and you will be [billed accordingly](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/understanding-cost-of-use#places-details). There is no way to constrain Nearby Search requests to only return specific fields. To keep from requesting (and paying for) data that you don't need, use a Find Place request instead.